# How to install sts in correct way

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Can someone explain me how should I install sts like some years back when I run some bash script and sts was installed ? With this new era when I just download sts and extract it to directory and run it I have a lot of problem. For example sometimes I can not open wsdl or xsd file in default editor and I need to use just text editor and so on. Here are error log of my sts:

http://pastebin.com/ePk7LnL2

I am using sts 3.6.3 download from this source: [sts3.6.3](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3.SR1/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.SR1-e4.4.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed additional plugins and it this looks like this caused a dependency issue between installed bundles. This disables certain bundles under the hood and that might cause the issues you describe.

I would recommend to download the latest STS 3.6.4 version and start with a test installation from scratch. Use that vanilla STS install to see what is working out-of-the-box and what not. If there is something not working, please file a bug at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS. If everything works as expected, install add-ons step-by-step to figure out which install breaks something else.

That way we can find out what is going wrong and how to fix that specific problem then.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it was fresh installation without any plugin. I found this bug in eclipse jira: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401717. It is very disappointing that they cant fix it in 2 years

Comment: Can't see how the Eclipse bug is related to your issue mentioned above. Did you try STS 3.6.4?

Comment: no I didnt try and I thinking to go back to version 3.2.0 where everythink works good